# Why strings in $_POST can not contain a dot "."?

Tags: php, post

Basicaly the title say's it all. i had an hidden input on my page where i wanted to set the name to "some.major.uber.setting"

for example:
`<input type="hidden" name="some.major.uber.setting" value="dummy value" />`

and when i looked at the $_POST data it contained "some_major_uber_setting". Can anybody explain this behaviour

Comment: just to be clear, i have register_global set to Off

Comment: That's why I said it's a relict. The php core replaces dots with underscores per default. That behaviour must've been introduced with register_globals and left untouched after removing it (or at least disabling it per default).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is probably a relict from `register_global = On` times. `$_GET`/`$_POST` variables were turned into standard variables (`$_GET['foo']` became `$foo`). Variable names can't contain dots so they were internally converted.

Answer (score 13):

This has been there since the [original commit to CVS](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/php_variables.c?revision=18892&view=markup#l76), more than 10 years ago.

It has a comment:

> /* ensure that we don't have spaces or dots in the variable name (not binary safe) */

I have no idea why it isn't "binary safe"... You'd have to ask Zeev.

Current link: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_variables.c#L93

Comment: Why not? `.` is a PHP operator.

Answer (score 8):

Its documented in [`php.net`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) as:

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores.

Comment: The OP knows that - it is stated as part of the question, which is "Why?"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my other answer, this is the function that fixes this unfortunate behaviour.

```
function fix(&$target, $source, $discard = true) {
    if ($discard)
        $target = array();

    $source = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|(?<=&))[^=[&]+/',
        function($key) { return bin2hex(urldecode($key[0])); },
        $source
    );

    parse_str($source, $post);
    foreach($post as $key => $val)
        $target[ hex2bin($key) ] = $val;
}
```

And then you can call this function like this:

```
fix($_POST, file_get_contents('php://input'));
```