# dot(.) not supported as array keys character after form submit

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have an array like:

```
$arr = array("a.b" => "a.b", "b.c" => "b.c");
```

When i print this it simply displays

```
Array ( [a.b] => a.b [b.c] => b.c )
```

But when i use a loop to use the key and value in checkbox name and values like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){?>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $v;?>" value="<?php echo $k;?>"><?php echo $v;?></li>
    <?php }?>
    </ul>
    <input name="sub" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When i press the submit button the result shows like:

```
Array ( [a_b] => a.b [b_c] => b.c [sub] => Submit )
```

Look at the output array, the keys are changed, The dot(.) replaces with **_**.

Why this happen??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why strings in $\_POST can not contain a dot "."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742653/why-strings-in-post-can-not-contain-a-dot)

Comment: This probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651/get-php-to-stop-replacing-characters-in-get-or-post-arrays

Comment: You mean just for `register_global` the index changed the dot with underscore??

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [variables.external documentation](http://www.php.net/variables.external)

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].

You can overcome this by using file_get_contents('php://input'); and then reading and parsing the input on your own if you cannot avoid dots in the variable names that come through GET or POST.